# More efficient way search for multiple objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I am currently using a for loop and multiple if statements to count the number of records that match a string.

```
for (var i = 0; i < DailyLogs.length; i++) {
  if (DailyLogs[i].created_at >= this.state.startMonth && DailyLogs[i].created_at <= this.state.finishMonth) {
    if (DailyLogs[i].created_by_id === "37aa0778-c148-4c04-b239-18885d46a8b0" ) { md1++; }
    if (DailyLogs[i].created_by_id === "869a7967-ffb3-4a20-b402-ad6d514472de" ) { md2++; }
    if (DailyLogs[i].created_by_id === "92c0f155-ce82-4b50-821f-439428c517a3" ) { md3++; }
    if (DailyLogs[i].created_by_id === "aa9eb0f2-35af-469a-8893-fc777b444bed" ) { md4++; }
    if (DailyLogs[i].created_by_id === "967d63ea-492c-4475-8b08-911be2d0bf22" ) { md5++; }
    if (DailyLogs[i].created_by_id === "47ec8d60-1fa2-4bf5-abc8-34df6bd53079" ) { md6++; }
    if (DailyLogs[i].created_by_id === "92c0f155-ce82-4b50-821f-439428c517a3" ) { md7++; }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, apart from having multiple if statements, or perhaps shorting this somehow.

Comment: What are the `md`s?

Comment: do you have more than the given `created_by_id` values?

Comment: just a global variable that holds the value. @NinaScholz

Comment: Judging from the hardcoded `md*` values it looks like you are counting the number of daily logs each user has submitted. May I suggest you to use some sort of "group by" operation in the database you are using? Most SQL engines come with such a feature, and it is better to do so in SQL. Particularly because the number of `md*` (users) may increase in future, which would require further code changes (in Javascript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it (slightly) more efficient by using `else if`, since if an earlier `if`'s condition is true, by definition later ones can't be.

Long series of `else if` in JavaScript can be written as `switch` instead.

```
for (var i = 0; i < DailyLogs.length; i++) {
  if (DailyLogs[i].created_at >= this.state.startMonth && DailyLogs[i].created_at <= this.state.finishMonth) {
      switch (DailyLogs[i].created_by_id) {
        case "37aa0778-c148-4c04-b239-18885d46a8b0": md1++; break;
        case "869a7967-ffb3-4a20-b402-ad6d514472de": md2++; break;
        case "92c0f155-ce82-4b50-821f-439428c517a3": md3++; break;
        case "aa9eb0f2-35af-469a-8893-fc777b444bed": md4++; break;
        case "967d63ea-492c-4475-8b08-911be2d0bf22": md5++; break;
        case "47ec8d60-1fa2-4bf5-abc8-34df6bd53079": md6++; break;
        case "92c0f155-ce82-4b50-821f-439428c517a3": md7++; break;
      }
  }
}
```

Using `else if` vs. `switch` is largely a matter of style in cases like this.

Another option is to maintain your counters in an object keyed by the `created_by_id`:

```
var md = {
    "37aa0778-c148-4c04-b239-18885d46a8b0": 0,
    "869a7967-ffb3-4a20-b402-ad6d514472de": 0,
    "92c0f155-ce82-4b50-821f-439428c517a3": 0,
    "aa9eb0f2-35af-469a-8893-fc777b444bed": 0,
    "967d63ea-492c-4475-8b08-911be2d0bf22": 0,
    "47ec8d60-1fa2-4bf5-abc8-34df6bd53079": 0,
    "92c0f155-ce82-4b50-821f-439428c517a3": 0
};
for (var i = 0; i < DailyLogs.length; i++) {
  if (DailyLogs[i].created_at >= this.state.startMonth && DailyLogs[i].created_at <= this.state.finishMonth && md.hasOwnProperty(DailyLogs[i].created_by_id)) {
      md[DailyLogs[i].created_by_id]++;
  }
}
```

You can also avoid the repeated `DailyLogs[i]` by using a variable in the loop body:

```
var log = DailyLogs[i];
if (log.created_at >= ...)
```

In modern ES2015+ environments, you can combine `for-of` with destructuring:

```
for (const {created_at, created_by_id} of DailyLogs) {
  if (created_at >= this.state.startMonth && created_at <= this.state.finishMonth) {
      switch (created_by_id) {
        case "37aa0778-c148-4c04-b239-18885d46a8b0": md1++; break;
        case "869a7967-ffb3-4a20-b402-ad6d514472de": md2++; break;
        case "92c0f155-ce82-4b50-821f-439428c517a3": md3++; break;
        case "aa9eb0f2-35af-469a-8893-fc777b444bed": md4++; break;
        case "967d63ea-492c-4475-8b08-911be2d0bf22": md5++; break;
        case "47ec8d60-1fa2-4bf5-abc8-34df6bd53079": md6++; break;
        case "92c0f155-ce82-4b50-821f-439428c517a3": md7++; break;
      }
  }
}
```

Those options can be combined in various ways, for instance:

```
const md = {
    "37aa0778-c148-4c04-b239-18885d46a8b0": 0,
    "869a7967-ffb3-4a20-b402-ad6d514472de": 0,
    "92c0f155-ce82-4b50-821f-439428c517a3": 0,
    "aa9eb0f2-35af-469a-8893-fc777b444bed": 0,
    "967d63ea-492c-4475-8b08-911be2d0bf22": 0,
    "47ec8d60-1fa2-4bf5-abc8-34df6bd53079": 0,
    "92c0f155-ce82-4b50-821f-439428c517a3": 0
};
for (const {created_at, created_by_id} of DailyLogs) {
  if (created_at >= this.state.startMonth && created_at <= this.state.finishMonth && md.hasOwnProperty(created_by_id)) {
      md[created_by_id]++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow lots of options and ideas, thank you for the depth of your response!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are merely counting, I would reccommend a map. This makes it easier to add more ids.

```
var counter = {
  '37aa0778-c148-4c04-b239-18885d46a8b0': 0,
  '869a7967-ffb3-4a20-b402-ad6d514472de': 0
}

function count(logs) {
  logs.filter(function(entry) {
    return entry.created_at >= this.state.startMonth &&
           entry.created_at <= this.state.finishMonth && 
           counter.hasOwnProperty(entry.created_by_id)
  }).forEach(function(entry) {
    counter[entry.created_by_id]++;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any time you find yourself creating variables in numeric sequence you should probably be using an array. Or in this case, you could use an object whose keys are the IDs you want to match.

```
var md = {
    "37aa0778-c148-4c04-b239-18885d46a8b0": 0,
    "869a7967-ffb3-4a20-b402-ad6d514472de": 0,
    ...
};
DailyLogs.forEach(l => 
    l.created_at >= this.state.startMonth && 
    l.created_at <= this.state.finishMonth && l.created_by_id in md && 
    md[l.created_by_id]++
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the id to check against in an object and update the the count.

```
var ids = {
        "37aa0778-c148-4c04-b239-18885d46a8b0": 0,
        "869a7967-ffb3-4a20-b402-ad6d514472de": 0,
        "92c0f155-ce82-4b50-821f-439428c517a3": 0,
        "aa9eb0f2-35af-469a-8893-fc777b444bed": 0,
        "967d63ea-492c-4475-8b08-911be2d0bf22": 0,
        "47ec8d60-1fa2-4bf5-abc8-34df6bd53079": 0,
        "92c0f155-ce82-4b50-821f-439428c517a3": 0
    };

DailyLogs.forEach(({ created_at: at, created_by_id: id }) => {
    if (at >= this.state.startMonth && at <= this.state.finishMonth && id in ids) {
        ids[id]++;
    }
});
```